# Need some explanation for the following bayesian graph

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian

I am trying to understand some lectures. A equation is presented as follows

[image]

I am confused with the first liner. Should it be  P(w,y |X) = P(y|X,w)P(X|w) P(w) ?? If the above were correct, would it mean that P(X|w) = 1. How should we explain this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this from some "data science" or "machine learning" class?  A lot of people post stuff like this on here from those sources.  The thing is, that crowd is just toying around with models that are not derived from anything. They just assert probabilistic and statistical relationships, then manipulate them, and fit models to data.  Trying to make sense of it as if it were derived from Bayes' rule or something is usually a mistake.

Comment: @Renard yah watching a lesson over there.... so it doesnt mean anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because we assume that $p(w|X) = p(w)$ (seeing values from r.v $X$ doesn't tell anything about distribution of  $w$ that you don't know before.which is pretty reasonable assumption  in case of linear regression )

$$p(w,y|X) = p(y|X,w) p(w|X) = p(y|X,w) p(w)$$

---

EDIT:Answer to question : Is $y$  marginally independent of 
$x$ ? is **NO**

$y$ is actually function of $x$ (which direct form of dependence)  Here is the rigorous proof . we will use gaussian marginal property that states as follows .

> $$\int_{z} \mathcal{N}(x|Az+b, L^{-1}) \mathcal{N}(z|\mu,\Lambda^{-1}) dz = \mathcal{N}(x|A\mu+b ,A\Lambda^{-1}A^{T}+L^{-1})$$

$$p(y|x) = \int_{w} p(y|w,x) p(w|x) dw = \int_{w}p(y|w,x)p(w) dw = \int_{w} \mathcal{N}(w^{T}x , \sigma^2I) \mathcal{N}(w|0,\gamma^2.I) dw = \mathcal{N}(0,\Big(\frac{x^{T}.x}{\gamma^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\Big).I ) $$

as you can $p(y|x)$ directly depends on $x$!

If your just starting in bayesian modelling . forget about the proof part just understand from the fact that $y = w^{T}.x $ ie( directly depends on $x$)

Comment: could we say that knowing X, does not tell you more about y? Or in your cases, shouldn't it be p(y|X,w)P(w)P(X)?

Comment: I get it! So X, w are considered to be independent of each other.. that's why P(w|X) = P(w)

Comment: @user1538798 added the proof. Ignore it if you don't understand and you can understand it later.

Comment: I get the idea that y is dependent on X from the graph relations... what i said earlier is not correct